# Oceanic Hostage Negotiation

Tags: environment, cataclysms

Help!

The moon was a spaceship all along, and it's inhabitants have finally woken up. They say that in order to continue on their travels, they need to take our oceans to create a bubble around their ship (don't ask me why, it makes no sense from my perspective). They say we shouldn't really worry about it, as we still have plenty of water vapour in the atmosphere - more than enough to survive on - but I just don't believe them, and I don't think many others do either.

I've been put in charge of coming up with a damage assessment, but I have no idea where to begin!

There was one final offer they made, before retreating back into their lunar home... they said they also really need gold, and are willing to trade some of our ocean water back to us - 1000 cubic miles of water per metric ton of gold we give them. Perhaps we can pay them off with enough to keep things going, if the situation is too dire, but I have no idea.

Help me, please, I can't afford to lose my job over this...

As people don't seem to understand what I'm asking, I'll clarify:

**Is there enough water in the atmosphere for humanity to survive on, if the oceans were stolen?**

**If not, would we be able to purchase enough with our gold reserves, to survive?**

Comment: I think humans can provide few hundred tons of gold for water, I guess. 1000 cubic miles of water? And why would they need gold anyway?

Comment: Using ice as a shield seems reasonable, send them off the harvest asteroids though, it's more practical than lifting tonnes of water out of a gravity well.

Comment: I'd just nuke the moon

Comment: I think your 2nd question can be easily answered by a simple google search.

Comment: @Separatrix They don't just want any old water, they want our oceans specifically. I think they have uses for the life contained within it, as they'll be taking them too.

Comment: @Raditz_35 Not if I don't know the answer to the first question, or how much we'd actually need to survive afterwards.

Comment: @CallumBradbury It would still be nice if you could provide the amount of water purchased (with your source for amount of gold) so that anyone who wants to answer doesn't need to do 30 minutes of research beforehand that you could've done yourself

Comment: @Raditz_35 It is not a question of how much we could purchase, it's a question of how much we would -need- to purchase. Two different things entirely.

Comment: @CallumBradbury So this is just one question: How much water does the planet need to survive? Then state it like this. People will be researching how much gold there is in the world and waste their time. Oh and btw, if you take all the life from the ocean - everything that needs oxygen dies. Keep that in mind

Comment: @Raditz_35 It takes like 2 seconds to find out how much gold there is in the world

Comment: @CallumBradbury That's what I've been saying - you could easily do this. Provide your numbers. Offer us your research so far. This sounds a lot like "do my work for me". Those numbers can vary btw depending on what you want. This is why it is so important to provide those numbers yourself

Answer (score 1):

So the moon has a surface of around 38,000,000 km². That would mean to surround the moon with a bubble of lets say 10 m of water you would need 380,000,000,000,000 m³ water. The earth has an ocean surface of 361,800,000,000,000  m² which would mean that the sea level of the earth would lower by 1 m, we would notice, but it's not *that* big a deal.

PS: It could be I messed up some zeros, but it's around that.

Comment: Where do you get your *10m* thickness for the water bubble from

Comment: @dot_Sp0T He didn't specify a thickness, so I chose one

Comment: I should possibly have clarified - they're taking it all, for a huge bubble. 10m isn't going to cut it for their schemes.

Comment: You need to express both areas in the same units to avoid the mistake you've made. It's about 1 meter. And we would notice that, although it wouldn't kill us.

Comment: meh, all my calculations....for nothing *sadface*

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast yeah you're right

Comment: You formatted k and m as *variables* in MathJax.  There’s no need for math formatting here anyway.